# Python - Update Jinja2 template multiple times and then render it

Tags: python, jinja2

I would like to update template several times and then render it. From [Jinja2 documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/api/#jinja2.Template.generate), I have found that:

> **generate()**
>
> For very large templates it can be useful to not
> render the whole template at once but evaluate each statement after
> another and yield piece for piece. This method basically does exactly
> that and returns a generator that yields one item after another as
> unicode strings.
>
> It accepts the same arguments as render().

This is my code and I don't know how to output/render `template`.

**template_render.py**

```
from jinja2 import Environment, Template, FileSystemLoader

file_loader = FileSystemLoader('templates')
env = Environment(loader=file_loader)

template = env.get_template('template_file.html')

template.generate(title='Lorem ipsum')
template.generate(subtitle='Dolor sit amet')

#How to render it now?
```

**template_file.html**

```
{{ title }} {{ subtitle }}
```

Comment: You don't seem to have understood that quote from the docs. `generate` is for iterating through a single template. To render a single template multiple times, just call render multiple times.

Comment: Maybe I have misleading question. Lets say that I want to update template with one variable, then do some calculations and update it with second variable etc. Finally I would like to print that rendered template without passing all the variables again.

Comment: You've probably misunderstood the use of this generator. It doesn't let you edit variables on the fly, it just splits **very large templates** into smaller parts. Why are you not getting all your variables ready before you render the template anyway?

Comment: yes stam is right, a generator will return the same thing as render for what you are interested in.
I don't understand why you would render the template multiple times, just get all your variables then render the template

Comment: I just think its easier in my case.